# API's calling twice while using interceptors in angular

Tags: angular

I am using two interceptors that intercept every request. One is used to add a token and next is used to show an error if the API call is not able to communicate with the backend.

**Token Interceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
  authService?: AuthService;
  constructor ( private inj: Injector,public errorHandler: ErrorHandler, ) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return this.authService
        .retrieveToken((req.url))
        .mergeMap((token: string) => {
          if (token !== null) {
            const request = req.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${ token }`}});
            return next.handle(request);
          }
          return next.handle(req);
        });
}
```

**Error Interceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    public errorHandler: ErrorHandler,
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          console.log(request);//It's displaying twice
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        this.errorHandler.handleError(err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**service.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    DataService,
    ErrorHandler,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    AuthService,
    AdalService,

  ]
})
export class ServicesModule { }
```

I am not able to find out the reason why the request is calling twice when I console the request in Error Interceptor. How to stop calling it twice?

Comment: How are you Retrieving the token? i.e. does "retriveToken" make a web request?

Comment: Yes, It's talking to Azure for the token. But Even though I am removing the token interceptor file, The API is still calling twice in error interceptor

Comment: Can you share your module file - where you register the interceptor

Comment: I have updated the question